# How to use object mapping with Flex, Zend, AMFPHP

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework

File structure

[image]

customerService.PHP

```
 include 'vo/VOCustomer.php';
 include 'mydb.php';
   
 class customerService 
 {    
  public function createCustomer(VOCustomer $cus)
  {
      $db = new mydb();
      $db->connect();
      
      $query = sprintf("insert into customer (CusId, CusName, CusContact,idcompany) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
      mysql_real_escape_string($cus->CusId),
      mysql_real_escape_string($cus->CusName),
      mysql_real_escape_string($cus->CusContact),
      mysql_real_escape_string($cus->idcompany));

      $rs = mysql_query($query) or die ("Unable to complete query.");
      
      return 'success';
  }
 }
```

vo/VOCustomer.php

```
class VOCustomer {
    public $CusId;
    public $CusName;
    public $CusContact;
    public $idcompany;
}
```

When importing the customerService.php to a flex zend project Its possible that the data type may not return as VOCustomer sometimes it will show **Object** as type

[image]

How to make the passing object as VOcustomer object ?

Comment: I believe you can modify the AS3 service class that was generated to take a typed parameter on the AS3 side.  Not sure why it didn't do this for you, if you allow it to generate the PHP and the AS3 DTOs and service classes based on a database (using the built-in template) it will show the parameter as a typed object.  After updating the AS3 service object you should be able to refresh that panel to see the changes reflected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the 'Connect to PHP' wizard understands type hinting.
Even if it does Zend AMF will pass an Objet not a VOCustomer to the method.
It's safer to add a PHPDoc comment:

```
/**
 * @param VOCustomer $cus
 */
public function createCustomer($cus)
```

Second add dummy function to your service that returns VOCustomer. The 'Connect to PHP' wizard generates a value object only if it's returned by a service method.

```
/**
 * @return VOCustomer
 */    
public function getCustomer() {
    //Do nothing
}
```